# Getting values from dynamically created JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, gettext

Could some please tell me why I'm not able to get the text value from my 'JTextFields' the way I have set it up.

I have the 'JTextFields' created based on the number of songs, but if I try to get the text from these fields the results are always blank?

```
JTextField[] digiProdDetailBx = new JTextField[p.getAlbum().getSongList().size()];
    JTextField[] digiProdDetailBx2 = new JTextField[p.getAlbum().getSongList().size()];
    JLabel[] digiProdDetailLb = new JLabel[p.getAlbum().getSongList().size()];


    for (int i = 0; i < p.getAlbum().getSongList().size(); i++) {

        int num = i +1;

        if (i == 0) {
            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            songs.add(songNumber, gc);
        }

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = i + 1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.gridheight = 1;
        gc.weighty = 0.0;
        gc.weightx = 2.0;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        digiProdDetailLb[i] = new JLabel(" " + num);
        digiProdDetailLb[i].setFont(font);
        songs.add(digiProdDetailLb[i], gc);

        if (i == 0) {
            gc.gridx = 1;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            songs.add(songName, gc);
        }
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = i + 1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.gridheight = 1;
        gc.weighty = 0.0;
        gc.weightx = 2.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;
        digiProdDetailBx[i] = new JTextField(p.getAlbum().getSongList().get(i).getSong_name());
        digiProdDetailBx[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 20));
        songs.add(digiProdDetailBx[i], gc);

        if (i == 0) {
            gc.gridx = 3;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            songs.add(songLength, gc);
        }
        gc.gridx = 3;
        gc.gridy = i + 1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.gridheight = 1;
        gc.weighty = 0.0;
        gc.weightx = 2.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;
        digiProdDetailBx2[i] = new JTextField(p.getAlbum().getSongList().get(i).getSong_length());
        digiProdDetailBx2[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
        songs.add(digiProdDetailBx2[i], gc);

    }
    ;

    this.add(songs, BorderLayout.EAST);


for(int i = 0 ; i < p.getAlbum().getSongList().size(); i++)
        {

            Song s = new Song(p.getProd_id(),p.getAlbum().getSongList().get(i).getProd_id(), 
                    digiProdDetailBx[i].getText(), digiProdDetailBx2[i].getText());
            alist.add(s);
        }


        for(int i = 0 ; i < alist.size(); i++)
        {
        System.out.println(digiProdDetailBx[i].getName());
        }
```

I'm assuming the way I have created the JTextFields is the problem, so is it possible to create them the way I had and still be able to get the values from them?

Comment: I figured out a work around by adding an array of named JTextFields,
is this the only/best way?

Comment: Does your `p.getAlbum().getSongList().get(i).getSong_name()` return proper, non-blank values? Also, you should stick to naming convention (getSongName()).

Comment: yes I have it working now, the naming convention got a bit messed up I started using the names from my tables as variable names, I'll be more careful on my next project.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < alist.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(digiProdDetailBx[i].getText());
}
```

The constructor you are using sets the text not the name, and `getName()` returns the name of the object, not the value.

By the way, it's generally more comfortable to use Lists rather than arrays and give them more meaningful names than somethingBX, somethingBX2 etc.

Comment: yes sorry I was testing something before I uploaded my code and forgot to change that back.